# About the Scalar product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

[image]

These are the lecture notes of my teacher and I am getting confused how he reached at $V_1$.$V_2$= Re($z_1$$z_2$). Can anyone help me to understand this.

Comment: what is $z_1\cdot z_2$

Comment: Multiply out $z_1\cdot z_2$ and find its real part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on is that the complex numbers are being considered as vectors in a two-dimensional plane. You can see that geometrically an X-Y plane represents a complex number of the form x + iy as the point (x, y), or equivalently by the vector connecting the origin to the point (x, y). The angle between two vectors in a two-dimensional plane is given by the scalar product formula shown in the lecture. Consider what the "angle between two complex numbers" actually means - it only makes geometrical sense when you consider the numbers as vectors in a 2-D plane.

Answer (score 1):

The last formula is wrong; there should be a complex conjugate on either $z_1$ or $z_2$. The formula should read $v_1\cdot v_2=\Re(z_1 \overline{z_2})=\Re(\overline{z_1} z_2)$. Now, you can verify the formula by expanding out both sides in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What are the assumptions for the first equation to be true in terms of $a_1, b_1, a_2$ and $b_2$?

Comment: @Kiran I don't understand the question.

Comment: For equation which involves $cos phi$, what assumptions one should made in terms of a1,b1,a2 and b2 to make it true

Comment: The equation $\cos\varphi=v_1\cdot v_2/(|v_1||v_2|)$ is true whenever both vectors are nonzero. If either of the vectors is zero, then $\varphi$ is undefined, and the right side of the equation is $0/0$.

Comment: you wrote in terms of $V_1$ and $V_2$, but I am interested to know in terms of $a_1$,$b_1$,$a_2$ and $b_2$. What you think if one write that $a_1$,$b_1$,$a_2$ and $b_2$ not equal to zero will it be fine

Answer (score 0):

$z_1=a_1+ib_1$ and $z_2=a_1+ib_1$
$z_1z_2=(a_1+ib_1)(a_2+ib_2)=a_1a_2+i(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)-b_1b_2$
$Re(z_1z_2)=a_1a_2-b_1b_2$

Comment: $Re(z_1 z_2)$= $V_1 V_2$ which is written earlier but you comes up with the same result which I was thinking. As per lecture notes it should be $a_1 a_2$+$b_1 b_2$

Comment: notes could be wrong